# AFMotor.h Throws Multiple Errors

Tags: arduino-uno, adafruit

I'm trying to get AFMotor.h working on an **Arduino Uno Wifi Rev2** with a **L293D Motor Shield**.

However, when I install the library (regardless of whether I do it using the in-built library manager or by downloading a zip and moving it to the relevant folder), the following errors get thrown on compilation.

```
In file included from c:\users\charya\documents\arduinodata\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5\avr\include\avr\io.h:99:0,
                 from c:\users\charya\documents\arduinodata\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5\avr\include\avr\pgmspace.h:90,
                 from C:\Users\Charya\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\arduino\hardware\megaavr\1.8.6\cores\arduino/api/String.h:31,
                 from C:\Users\Charya\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\arduino\hardware\megaavr\1.8.6\cores\arduino/api/Print.h:24,
                 from C:\Users\Charya\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\arduino\hardware\megaavr\1.8.6\cores\arduino/api/Stream.h:25,
                 from C:\Users\Charya\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\arduino\hardware\megaavr\1.8.6\cores\arduino/api/Client.h:22,
                 from C:\Users\Charya\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\arduino\hardware\megaavr\1.8.6\cores\arduino/api/ArduinoAPI.h:29,
                 from C:\Users\Charya\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\arduino\hardware\megaavr\1.8.6\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:23,
                 from sketch\code.ino.cpp:1: C:\Users\Charya\Documents\Arduino\libraries\afmotor/AFMotor.h:49:30: error: 'CS01' was not declared in this scope
     #define MOTOR34_8KHZ _BV(CS01)              // divide by 8
                              ^ C:\Users\Charya\Documents\Arduino\libraries\afmotor/AFMotor.h:52:33: note: in expansion of macro 'MOTOR34_8KHZ'
     #define DC_MOTOR_PWM_RATE   MOTOR34_8KHZ    // PWM rate for DC motors
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~ C:\Users\Charya\Documents\Arduino\libraries\afmotor/AFMotor.h:156:47: note: in expansion of macro 'DC_MOTOR_PWM_RATE'    AF_DCMotor(uint8_t motornum, uint8_t freq = DC_MOTOR_PWM_RATE);
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ C:\Users\Charya\Documents\Arduino\libraries\afmotor/AFMotor.h:49:30: note: suggested alternative: 'B101'
     #define MOTOR34_8KHZ _BV(CS01)              // divide by 8
                              ^ C:\Users\Charya\Documents\Arduino\libraries\afmotor/AFMotor.h:52:33: note: in expansion of macro 'MOTOR34_8KHZ'
     #define DC_MOTOR_PWM_RATE   MOTOR34_8KHZ    // PWM rate for DC motors
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~ C:\Users\Charya\Documents\Arduino\libraries\afmotor/AFMotor.h:156:47: note: in expansion of macro 'DC_MOTOR_PWM_RATE'    AF_DCMotor(uint8_t motornum, uint8_t freq = DC_MOTOR_PWM_RATE);
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ exit status 1 Error compiling for board Arduino Uno WiFi Rev2.
```

I've also attached an image of the error if that's easier to read. I have no code written, and I am only importing the library and compiling it.

What am I doing wrong? I'm unsure what's even happening. [image: Errors]

Comment: Looks like the library doesn't support the newer MegaAVR chips, and the "compatibility layer" either isn't working or you have it turned off.

Comment: have you examined any example code that may be included with the library?

Comment: I have the same problem.
When I am using an Arduino Uno board the sketch is compiled without errors.
When I am using an Arduino Wifi Rev 2 board I get the same error messages.
My feeling is, that the AFMotor library is not compatible for Arduini Wifi 2 boards.